# How to implement DatePicker in my Google Apps Scripts

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I would like to make the two dates start_date_cal and end_date_cal chosen by the user who is running the script below.

By reading a lot about how to do that, I have found plenty about Html Services, but I couldn't successed in implementing it in my code.

```
function main_cotisations() {
var cell_col_number = "";
var cell_row_number = "";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('2019-2020');
//ss.setActiveSelection('A3');
ss.getRange('A3').activate();

// Get active cell and get value of it
var cell = ss.getCurrentCell();
var cellValue = cell.getValue();

var start_date_cal = new Date('December 12, 2019 19:00:00 +1100');
var end_date_cal = new Date('December 12, 2019 22:30:00 +1100');

// Start the loop
while (cellValue != ""){
  cellValue = cell.getValue();
  if (cellValue != "") {

  var infos_user = {};
  infos_user.prenom = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()+2).getValue();
  infos_user.mail = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()+3).getValue();
  infos_user.solde_a_payer = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()+8).getValue();
  infos_user.url_calendar = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/render?action=TEMPLATE&text=Penser+aux+capitations+: '+infos_user.solde_a_payer+'F&location=Ducos&dates='+getRelativeDate(start_date_cal)+'%2F'+getRelativeDate(end_date_cal);

  if (sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),cell.getColumn()+9).isChecked()  == false) {
    sendmail_paiement(infos_user);  
  }
  };
  cell = cell.offset(1, 0);
};  

var infos_globales = {};
infos_globales.solde_global = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow()-1,cell.getColumn()+8).getValue();
infos_globales.nb_user_hospitalier = sheet.getRange(cell.getRow()-1,cell.getColumn()+9).getValue();
infos_globales.nb_user_retard =sheet.getRange(cell.getRow()-1,cell.getColumn()+10).getValue();
}

//***********************************************************************************************************************

function getRelativeDate(given_date) {
//{given_date = Utilities.formatDate(temp_date, "GMT", "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");}
temp = Utilities.formatDate(given_date, "GMT", "yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss'Z'");
return temp.toString();
}

function sendmail_paiement(infos_user) {

 var templ = HtmlService
.createTemplateFromFile('tpl_mail_exceptionnel');

templ.infos_user = infos_user;
var message = templ.evaluate().getContent();

if (infos_user.solde_a_payer>0) {
  MailApp.sendEmail(
    infos_user.mail,
    "Rappel de capitations", 
    '', 
    {htmlBody: message,}
  );
}
}
```

I would appreciate some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be implemented by developing an [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) from there you could create a form with a date picker and a submit button to send the date back to the apps script and execute your code.

I've done a little demo:

Go apps script and make a new project:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameter.start);
  Logger.log(e.parameter.end);
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("Hi there, <br> When you click submit doPost() function is called. <br> By calling e.parameter.start you'll get the desired dates <br> Like:" +e.parameter.start+ "<br>Now check the logs. <br> Good luck");
}

function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
}
```

Now, on apps script, press File --> New --> Html file --> Name it 'index'

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="PASTE_YOUR_WEBAPP_LINK_HERE" method="post">
    <label for="start">Start date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="start" name="start"
    value="2019-10-21"
    min="2019-01-01" max="2020-12-31">
    <input type="date" id="end" name="end"
    value="2019-10-22"
    min="2019-01-01" max="2020-12-31">    
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form> 
  </body>
</html>
```

- Go to Publish --> Deploy as Web App
- Copy the link and post it inside the index HTML file, were it says PASTE_YOUR_WEBAPP_LINK_HERE

Now you can visit your deployed WebApp:

Anytime you click submit you'll call doPost() function.

So, now you can paste your code inside doPost() function, you can use the dates from the datepicker and execute any apps script you wish.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi yuri and thanks for your help!
The thing I'm missing is that actually I'm running my script without using and Html page that is displayed, so how can I run the web app directly from my function mail_cotisations() to get the two dates value I picked up in your Date Picker project?

Comment: If you want to execute the function mail_cotisations() once the dates are picked on the web app and submit is clicked paste your inner mail_cotisations() content inside the doPost function. You'll need to change the dates variables for the dates provided by the Datepicker, start_date_cal = e.parameter.start
```

Comment: Ok I could manage your code running in another projetct > deploying it as a Web App but when I try to integer it in my code as you said when I run the Macro doPost() I got an error "TypeError: Cannot read property "parameter" from undefined"
`function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e.parameter.start);
  Logger.log(e.parameter.end);
...
And added all the inner code of main_Capitations()
}

function doGet(e) {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('date_picker');
}`

Comment: Anytime you attempt to this doPost function by itself you'll get this error. doPost needs to have an input parameter (e) that should had been send by a post request, if not, e.parameter.start can not have any value, it'll be undefined as you are seeing. 

So, a doPost function like that has to be called by a post request, as it was specified on the main answer: Follow the steps I provided and then visit the link of the webapp, when you click submit you'll send the parameters thru a post request to the doPost function, and then, you'll not see this error cause the parameters would exist.